# java: highlight dom element on mouseover and mouse out

Tags: java, swing, domdocument

```
 DOMDocument.addEventListener("mousemove", new EventListener() {                            
                        public void handleEvent(Event evt) {     
                            System.out.println(evt.getType().toString());

                                final DOMElement targetElement = (DOMElement) browserDocument.getElementfromPixelPosition(mpl.screenX, mpl.screenY);
                                targetElement.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid red;");

                                targetElement.addEventListener("mouseout", new EventListener() {                            
                                    public void handleEvent(Event evt) { 
                                        System.out.println(evt.getType().toString());
                                        targetElement.setAttribute("style", "border:none;");
                                }
                            }, false);
                        }
                    }, false);
```

I want a red border to highlight elements on mouseover. on mouseout, I want it to disappear.

How to fix it? The code I wrote doesn't work too well.

Comment: What GUI library are you using?  Can you provide more details regarding your problem?

Comment: You did not post how your DOMDocument is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example illustrating what you asked

This example applies the border to a `JPanel`, you can modify it to work with your `dom element`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class HighlightBorder extends MouseAdapter {

    JPanel p;
    LineBorder border;

    public HighlightBorder() {
        JFrame j = new JFrame();
        p = new JPanel();
        border = new LineBorder(Color.red, 2);
        j.getContentPane().add(p);
        j.setSize(400, 300);
        j.setVisible(true);
        p.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        p.setBorder(border);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        p.setBorder(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HighlightBorder();
    }
}
```